# Ошибка при сравнении текстовых столбцов в Mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Возникает ошибка **illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci implicit)** при запросе вида **left join on t1.login = t2.login**.
Оба столбца - типа Text, кодировка таблицы одинаковая.
В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Нужно посмотреть виды сравнения (collation), а не кодировку таблиц (charset).
Посмотрел так:

```
SELECT 
   table_schema,
   table_name,
   table_collation   
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema in('users', 'orders', 'documents');
```

Пришел такой ответ:

```
table_schema table_name table_collation
users list utf8_unicode_ci
users roles utf8_unicode_ci
orders list utf8_general_ci
documents list utf8_general_ci
```

Тут я вижу, что у **users.list и documents.list** разные типы сравнения.
Исправил сравнение (collation) у одной из таблиц:

```
alter table users.list convert to character set utf8mb3 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Кодировка utfm8b3 может быть другой в зависимости от версии, как я полагаю. Мне подошла utf8bm3 как синоним utf8.